# Choosing training data inputs to optimize approximation

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, optimization, experiment-design, approximation

Suppose you have a smooth function $f^*:D_1 \times D_2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that you observe with error as $f$ such that $$f(x,y)=f^*(x,y)+\epsilon$$ where $\epsilon$ has zero expectation (you can add more assumptions if necessary, e.g., that $f^*$ is a linear combination of a finite collection of basis functions and $\epsilon$ is Gaussian). The function $f$ is expensive to evaluate, so we seek a parametric approximation $p_\theta$ such that $$\sum_i(f(x_i,y_i)-p_\theta(x_i,y_i))^2$$ is minimized.

Suppose we are allowed to choose our input data $\{x_i,y_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$. **Is their an optimal choice of points $\{x_i,y_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$?**

"Optimal" here could mean minimizing the expected mean squared error given some distribution on $x,y$, or whatever is more convenient. The goal is to get a decent picture of $f^*$ using a limited number of observations of $f$. Naively, I might choose $x,y$ to be the Cartesian products of the roots of the $n^{1/2}$th degree orthogonal polynomials on $D_1,D_2$, respectively, but perhaps there is something more sensible.

Comment: This is a good question.  Naively, your question is about $x_i$, not the $y_i$ since you presumably only have control over the $y_i$ through the $x_i$ and no control over the error term. I'm just thinking out loud but will get back to this

Comment: Have you read into Response Surface Methodology?

Comment: @DemetriPananos I think the $x$, $y$ was a poor choice of notation on my part. Both $x$,$y$ are inputs, and $f(x,y)$ is observed. But I think you have the general idea:you choose inputs and your training data consist of the input points x,y) and the observed f(x,y).

Comment: Have not read into response surfaces but it sounds promising

Comment: Whoops, misread that.  Same idea applies.

Comment: From my glimpse into RSM I haven't been able to find anything about the problem of choosing the data points. The closest related problems I've run into are multidimensional Gaussian quadrature (the basis for my "naive" choice of the zeros of orthogonal polynomials) and low discrepancy sequences, which I think applies to the case where the number of points gets progressively larger rather than staying fixed...

Comment: Possibly also related to experimental design

Comment: What objects are $D_1$ and $D_2$?  For example, if they are intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ and if $p_\theta$ is a linear model then there are efficient ways to search for locations of points that minimize the integral of the variance of the prediction surface (I-optimal designs), minimize the max variance across the prediction surface (G-optimal designs), and some others.

Comment: @neverKnowsBest $D_1$ and $D_2$ are indeed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. The methods you're describing sound like a noisy version of quadrature rules for minimizing $\ell_2$ and $\ell_\infty$ errors of integration a polynomial approximation?

Comment: I think that's the right idea, except that (for a linear model polynomial approximation) it's not the error of the polynomial approximation but the variance of the fitted approximation.  We don't often use standardized designs in RSM because we often have unique constraints per problem.  You could use $p_\theta(\cdot, \cdot)$ directly (under mild regularity conditions) and simply optimize those criteria, it's just the problem becomes computationally more difficult.